# Set Mongo Timeout in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I am using spring boot web application which connects to mongo db which is working out of the box. I just use the following properties:

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=myHost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=myDatabase
spring.data.mongo.repositories.enabled=true
spring.data.mongodb.username=myUser
spring.data.mongodb.password=myPassword
```

The default timeout to MongoDB is 10 seconds. I would like to configure the timeout. I tried doing
     `spring.data.mongodb.socketTimeout=2` or       `spring.data.mongodb.connectionTimeout=2`

None of the properties work. Is it something that I can specify in the properties and the Spring framework will take care of it or can someone give example of doing it by declaring the Bean.

Answer (score 20):

To follow your theme, this would be the best to answer your question.
Looks like you would like to set a timeout in your application.properties file.

In order to do so:

**Instead of**

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=myHost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=myDatabase

spring.data.mongodb.username=myUser
spring.data.mongodb.password=myPassword
```

**Try this**

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://myUser:myPassword@myHost:27017,myHost:27017/myDatabase?serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&connectTimeoutMS=2000
spring.data.mongodb.database=myDatabase
spring.data.mongo.repositories.enabled=true
```

Modify time in milliseconds to desired time.

Comment: Is there any option to give autoreconnect in spring.data.mongodb.uri ?

Comment: @PSatishPatro No need, if connection works properly, it will automatically reconnect. If you're using the mongo dependency.

Comment: Nice @Jesse. Did not know that

Comment: @Jesse. I am getting this error if i am trying to access mongodb after so much of time around 9hrs. Reponse code - 500 In response header - connection close. https://textuploader.com/15s28

Comment: @PSatishPatro Did you set a timeout limit? I would suggest to connect to the mongoDB manually first to ensure connection is working properly.

Comment: I have not set timeout. I am using it in spring boot. When hitting controller to retrive data it shows the error. But, If I am hitting the same controller 2nd/3rd time, it is showing data

Comment: One time even it showed this error in swagger and simultaneoulsy showed output in response with out executing again. Once only

Comment: @PSatishPatro Understood you're getting a timeout error. I suggest you to create a post on this issue. I need to see your pom.xml/build.gradle and how you're setting up for mongoDB with springboot.

Answer (score 16):

This will override the Spring Boot autoconfiguration:

```
@Configuration
public class MongoDbSettings {

    @Bean
    public MongoClientOptions mongoOptions() {
        return MongoClientOptions.builder().socketTimeout(2000).build();
    }

}
```

Comment: Seems like this should be unnecessary. You also need to set all the other properties via this bean instead of using the properties and spring datasource to build the bean for you.

Answer (score 8):

For Spring Data with Reactive MongoDb:

My case was a bit different (I had closing connections - which throws "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: state should be: open")

But You can use this with your case.

**application.yml:**

```
spring.data.mongodb:
  host: localhost
  database: myDb
  port: 27017
  username: admin
  password: test
```

If Your implementation use **MongoReactiveAutoConfiguration** for bean creation, then You can configure it with this bean:

```
@Bean
public MongoClientSettings mongoClientSettings() {
    final MongoClientSettings clientSettings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
            .retryWrites(true)
            .applyToConnectionPoolSettings((ConnectionPoolSettings.Builder builder) -> {
                builder.maxSize(300) //connections count
                        .minSize(100)
                        .maxConnectionLifeTime(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                        .maxConnectionIdleTime(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                        .maxWaitTime(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                        .maxWaitQueueSize(5000);
            })
            .applyToSocketSettings(builder -> {
                builder.connectTimeout(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            })
            .applicationName("app")
            .build();

    return clientSettings;
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for anyone using the latest versions of spring.

Answer (score 5):

[MongoClientOptions](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/MongoClientOptions.Builder.html) is a class which has the required properties.

**Programmatically**
If you have configured your MongoDB programmatically, then below is the code snippet to help you out.

```
DB mongoDb;

MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress(url, port), 
                            MongoClientOptions.builder()
                            .socketTimeout(3000)
                            .minHeartbeatFrequency(25)
                            .heartbeatSocketTimeout(3000)
                            .build());
mongoDb = mongoClient.getDB(dbname);
```

**XML Configuration - Advanced**

```
<beans>

  <mongo:mongo host="localhost" port="27017">
    <mongo:options connections-per-host="8"
                   threads-allowed-to-block-for-connection-multiplier="4"
                   connect-timeout="1000"
                   max-wait-time="1500}"
                   auto-connect-retry="true"
                   socket-keep-alive="true"
                   socket-timeout="1500"
                   slave-ok="true"
                   write-number="1"
                   write-timeout="0"
                   write-fsync="true"/>
  </mongo:mongo/>

</beans>
```

Also refer [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.mongo-xml-config) for complete documentation.

Answer (score 3):

The question is old but for all those who have problems with Mongo DB JAVA driver timeouts : set the maxConnectionIdleTime property.

Example Spring Boot :

```
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientOptions;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnClass;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnMissingBean;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

@Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass(MongoClient.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MongoProperties.class)
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(type = "org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoDbFactory")
public class MongoAutoConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private MongoProperties properties;

    @Autowired(required = false)
    private MongoClientOptions options;

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    private MongoClient mongo;

    @PreDestroy
    public void close() {
        if (this.mongo != null) {
            this.mongo.close();
        }
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    public MongoClient mongo() throws UnknownHostException {
        this.options = options.builder().maxConnectionIdleTime(1000 * 60 * 4).build();
        this.mongo = this.properties.createMongoClient(this.options, this.environment);
        return this.mongo;
    }
}
```

A very useful link here : [Java DriverJAVA-2535 com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException ......](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-2535)

Comment: is it not possible to have it in the application.properties as spring.data.maxConnectionIdleTime = 123 ?

Comment: @bleh10 I didn't try.

Answer (score 2):

The question was specifically for Spring boot. I am using the following approach which works well, please suggest if there is a way not to use new and use Spring for configuring it.

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;
 import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
 import org.springframework.data.mongodb.config.AbstractMongoConfiguration;
 import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoMappingContext;
 import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableMongoRepositories;
 import com.mongodb.Mongo;
 import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
 import com.mongodb.MongoClientOptions;
 import com.mongodb.MongoCredential;
 import com.mongodb.ServerAddress;

 @Configuration
 @EnableMongoRepositories("com.myapp.repository")
 public class SpringMongoConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

@Value("${myapp.mongodb.host}")
private String host;

@Value("${myapp.mongodb.port}")
private int port;

@Value("${myapp.mongodb.database}")
private String mongoDB;

@Value("${myapp.mongodb.userName}")
private String userName;

@Value("${myapp.mongodb.password}")
private String password;

@Value("${myapp.mongodb.socketTimeoutMS}")
private int socketTimeout;

@Value("${myapp.mongodb.connectionTimeoutMS}")
private int connectionTimeout;

@Override
public MongoMappingContext mongoMappingContext() throws ClassNotFoundException {
return super.mongoMappingContext();
}

@Override
@Bean
public Mongo mongo() throws Exception {

List<ServerAddress> servers = new ArrayList<ServerAddress>();
servers.add(new ServerAddress(host, port));

List<MongoCredential> creds = new ArrayList<MongoCredential>();
creds.add(MongoCredential.createCredential(userName, mongoDB, password.toCharArray()));

MongoClientOptions builder = MongoClientOptions.builder().socketTimeout(socketTimeout).connectTimeout(connectionTimeout).build();

return new MongoClient(servers, creds, builder);
}

@Override
protected String getDatabaseName() {
return mongoDB;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want just customize one or othere MongoClientSettings instead returning one with all settings filled, better use the following:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoClientSettingsBuilderCustomizer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

@Configuration
public class MongoDbSettings {

    private static final int CONNECTION_POOL_SIZE = 10;
    private static final int CONNECTION_POOL_MIN_SIZE = 1;
    private static final int CONNECTION_POOL_MAX_IDLE_TIME = 3;
    private static final int CONNECTION_POOL_MAX_WAIT_TIME = 10;
    private static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 3;

    @Value("${spring.application.name}")
    private String applicationName;

    @Bean
    public MongoClientSettingsBuilderCustomizer mongoClientSettingsBuilderCustomizer() {
        return custom -> custom.applyToSocketSettings(builder ->
                        builder.connectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                .readTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                .applyToConnectionPoolSettings(builder ->
                        builder.maxSize(CONNECTION_POOL_SIZE)
                                .minSize(CONNECTION_POOL_MIN_SIZE)
                                .maxConnectionIdleTime(CONNECTION_POOL_MAX_IDLE_TIME, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                .maxWaitTime(CONNECTION_POOL_MAX_WAIT_TIME, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                .applyToClusterSettings(builder ->
                        builder.serverSelectionTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                .applicationName(applicationName)
                ;
    }
```

Answer (score -5):

I found the following document with a possible solution.

https://www.programmersought.com/article/1927319190/

It mentions the following:

```
spring.data.mongodb.address=172.16.250.234:27017,172.16.250.239:27017,172.16.250.240:27017
spring.data.mongodb.replica-set=rs0
spring.data.mongodb.database=test
spring.data.mongodb.username=admin
spring.data.mongodb.password=admin

# Configure spring.data.mongodbDB Pool
spring.data.mongodb.min-connections-per-host=10
spring.data.mongodb.max-connections-per-host=100
spring.data.mongodb.threads-allowed-to-block-for-connection-multiplier=5
spring.data.mongodb.server-selection-timeout=30000
spring.data.mongodb.max-wait-time=120000
spring.data.mongodb.max-connection-idel-time=0
spring.data.mongodb.max-connection-life-time=0
spring.data.mongodb.connect-timeout=10000
spring.data.mongodb.socket-timeout=0
spring.data.mongodb.socket-keep-alive=false
spring.data.mongodb.ssl-enabled=false
spring.data.mongodb.ssl-invalid-host-name-allowed=false
spring.data.mongodb.always-use-m-beans=false
spring.data.mongodb.heartbeat-socket-timeout=20000
spring.data.mongodb.heartbeat-connect-timeout=20000
spring.data.mongodb.min-heartbeat-frequency=500
spring.data.mongodb.heartbeat-frequency=10000
spring.data.mongodb.local-threshold=15
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=auth_dev
```

I'm trying to test this now to make sure it is working, but it at least seems plausible.

Comment: The article you reference also shows that it requires custom code to ingest these and programmatically set them into a MongoClientOptions.Builder() instance. There is nothing automatic here. (The use of spring.data prefix in the property names might suggest that, but that was just the author's choice, and one that I would avoid for that reason). Moreover, MongoClientOptions is no longer in the current version of Spring. 

Also, in the future, probably best to test your idea first, and only post it if it works.