# Spring MongoDB: Server instantly closing connection after starting

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

This is my first time using MongoDB with Spring, and all I'm trying to do is start the Spring server however the connection closes straight away after it's opened.

After looking around on similar scenarios, there were suggestions about removing the Spring Data JPA dependency which I did but did not help. Another suggestion said to add h2 as a dependency to as Spring Starter needed it before a few things, which did help as previous the connection didn't even open. I've also edited the properties file, but nothing seems to work.

Gradle file:

```
group = 'com.danielturato'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=mongo
server.port=8095
```

The logs:

```
2019-08-22 00:04:13.109  INFO 16376 --- [           main] com.danielturato.esports.Application     : Starting Application on DESKTOP-E2MJ251 with PID 16376 (started by danie in D:\Projects\eSports Project)
2019-08-22 00:04:13.111  INFO 16376 --- [           main] com.danielturato.esports.Application     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-08-22 00:04:13.368  INFO 16376 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019-08-22 00:04:13.411  INFO 16376 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 39ms. Found 1 repository interfaces.
2019-08-22 00:04:14.117  INFO 16376 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=MULTIPLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
2019-08-22 00:04:14.117  INFO 16376 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Adding discovered server localhost:27017 to client view of cluster
2019-08-22 00:04:14.150  INFO 16376 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:14}] to localhost:27017
2019-08-22 00:04:14.153  INFO 16376 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[4, 2, 0]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=8, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=1950400}
2019-08-22 00:04:14.154  INFO 16376 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Discovered cluster type of STANDALONE
2019-08-22 00:04:14.378  INFO 16376 --- [           main] com.danielturato.esports.Application     : Started Application in 1.482 seconds (JVM running for 1.99)
2019-08-22 00:04:14.414  INFO 16376 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:15}] to localhost:27017
2019-08-22 00:04:14.429  INFO 16376 --- [       Thread-2] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:15}] to localhost:27017 because the pool has been closed.
```

If anyone has anymore suggestions, that would be appreciated !

Comment: This might be a configuration issue. Maybe your timeouts are too small? Also, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39703240/how-to-keep-the-connection-pool-from-closing-with-a-java-driver-on-a-mongodb)

Comment: I just tried the solution in that question, and it didn't work, still the same log messages

Comment: How about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39851184/3641067)? Are you using such a configuration in your code? If you do, please include it in your question!

Comment: Have you a customer configuration file? Can you please post your entire pom.xml file and all related configuration files ?

Comment: I've posted all the relevant files, I have no external configuration apart from what I've already put in the question. The only other files I have is a User model, repository and Rest Controller and a Command Line Runner to inject 3 Users into the database