# How to modify the number of milliseconds (30000 ms by default) that a Spring Boot application takes to connect to a MongoDB database?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

My understanding is that if my MongoDB database is not running, my Spring Boot application will take 30000ms by default to try to connect to the database.

How can I modify the value of 30000 ms? I tried putting the following in the application.properties but it doesn't work:

```
spring.data.mongodb.option.server-selection-timeout=1000
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63924999/12312156
Does this answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set Mongo Timeout in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36784017/set-mongo-timeout-in-spring-boot)